# Error passing ArrayList of parcelable object

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable

I have a strange error in my app on Android Studio trying to pass ArrayList of parcelable objects between activities. It's possible to pass the objet Task but impossible to pass an ArrayList of task with putParcelableArrayListExtra.
I have this error

```
02-10 20:27:46.567: E/AndroidRuntime(12683): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@9d0525e8: Unmarshalling unknown type code 2097253 at offset 128
02-10 20:27:46.567: E/AndroidRuntime(12683):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2080)
02-10 20:27:46.567: E/AndroidRuntime(12683):    at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2343)
02-10 20:27:46.567: E/AndroidRuntime(12683):    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1703)
02-10 20:27:46.567: E/AndroidRuntime(12683):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2034)
02-10 20:27:46.567: E/AndroidRuntime(12683):    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2314)
02-10 20:27:46.567: E/AndroidRuntime(12683):    at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
02-10 20:27:46.567: E/AndroidRuntime(12683):    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:1250)
02-10 20:27:46.567: E/AndroidRuntime(12683):    at android.content.Intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.java:4680)
02-10 20:27:46.567: E/AndroidRuntime(12683):    at com.example.augus.tp2.NewActivity$1.onClick(NewActivity.java:51)
```

This is my class Task:

```
public class Task implements Parcelable {
public String nom;
private int duree;
private String description;
private String categorie;

public Task(String nom, int duree, String description, String categorie){
    this.nom=nom;
    this.duree=duree;
    this.description=description;
    this.categorie=categorie;

}


protected Task(Parcel in) {
    nom = in.readString();
    duree = in.readInt();
    description = in.readString();
    categorie = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<Task> CREATOR = new Creator<Task>() {
    @Override
    public Task createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Task(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Task[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Task[size];
    }
};

public String getNom(){
    return this.nom;
}

public String getCategorie(){
    return this.categorie;
}

public int getDuree(){
    return this.duree;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return this.description;
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(nom);
    dest.writeString(description);
    dest.writeInt(duree);
    dest.writeString(categorie);
}
}
```

This is the function OnClick passing the ArrayList

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent secondActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);

            ArrayList<Task> list=new ArrayList<Task>();
            list.add(task1);
            list.add(task2);
            list.add(task3);
            list.add(task4);
            list.add(task5);
            list.add(task6);
            list.add(task7);
            secondActivity.putParcelableArrayListExtra("task",list);
            startActivity(secondActivity);
        }
```

And this is the function receiving the ArrayList

```
Intent secondeActivite = new Intent(NewActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            String activitenom = nom.getText().toString();
            String activitedescription=description.getText().toString();
            String activitecategorie=categorie.getText().toString();
            Intent i = getIntent();
            Task tache=new Task(activitenom,10,activitedescription,activitecategorie);

            ArrayList<Task> tacheliste=i.getParcelableArrayListExtra("task");
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The order of your elements in `Task(Parcel in)` and `writeToParcel` have to be in the same order. `duree` and `description` needs to be swapped in one of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sorry the code is in `kotlin`

constructor(source: Parcel) : this(
        source.readString(),
        source.readInt(),
        source.readString(),
        source.readString()
)

override fun describeContents() = 0

override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) = with(dest) {
    writeString(nom)
    writeInt(duree)
    writeString(description)
    writeString(categorie)
}
```

The order should be the same